# Derby database management tool

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

is there any management tool for Derby database like razorSQL ? I tried to use razorSQL, but it seems to be a not good choice for me.

Comment: RazorSQL is supposed to work with Derby. In what way is it not a good choice for you?

Comment: SquirrelSQL, H2 database web console (you need to add the jars for the driver) and Eclipse all have decent Database support. It really depends on what you're after but the H2 web console has auto-complete and is very easy to work from. I hate the interface on Squirrel, but it is extremely powerful.

Comment: I have some problems with razorSQL like autoincrement (identity column). If I want to add some data over razorSQL it generates null in identity column in sql query and that causes an error becouse identity column can't be null, so in this case it isn't autoincrement at all. Adding data from java code works fine. Do I something wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few useful Derby tools:

- [Eclipse built-in DataSource Explorer](http://www.google.com/search?q=Eclipse%20Data%20Source%20Explorer%20for%20Derby). Fine only for the most basic tasks, table view cannot even order by columns, nor can it filter records, so every such thing must be done by SQL. It's just one notch better than a shell tool.
- [DBVisualizer, free edition](http://www.google.com/search?q=DBVisualizer,%20free%20edition). Better than Eclipse's, but the free edition has many deliberate shortcomings, which must be paid for to make them go away.
- [SQuirreL SQL Client](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/SQuirreL_Derby.html) is also a useful tool for browsing and manipulating SQL databases via JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

I had used Derby on Netbeans, and hadn't faced with problems you mentioned. So I can suggest you to use that.